# Can I draw great circle segment (geodesic) lines in Openlayers 3?

Tags: openlayers-3

I want to plot lines between (distant) points on an Openlayers 3 map (which uses Open Street Map tiles). I want the lines to be seen as curves, as with flight paths, since they should take the shortest real world surface path: a geodesic (a great circle segment).

Is this possible?

Would I need to interpolate the points along the geodesic (how?) and plot a bunch of line segments, or is there an easier way? Is there something built in I can't find, or a library for it?

Comment: I guess this (https://github.com/springmeyer/arc.js) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Cool, I'll likely try to use that with OL3 in the next few days. I'll report back. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at OL3's [Flight Animation Example](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.12.1/examples/flight-animation.html), it appears to be possible using the [arc.js](https://github.com/springmeyer/arc.js) plugin: “A great circle arc between two airports is calculated using arc.js and then the flight paths are animated with postcompose. The flight data is provided by [OpenFlights](http://openflights.org/data.html) (a simplified data set from the Mapbox.js documentation is used).”
[image: Screenshot of OpenLayers3's Flight Animation Example]